# keep XY Graph legend from overlapping plot?

Tags: user-interface, graph, labview

I have an XY graph with a legend that automatically resizes to fit the contents of the legend.  The problem is that sometimes the legend text is such that the resizing overlaps the plot, [see the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qozjc.png).  Is there a way to keep the legend from resizing over the plot data?  In other words to confine the resizing operation to outside of the plot box?

Update: it would seem that part of the problem is the auto expand ability of the legend always expands to the left-hand side. Placing the legend on the left-hand side of the plot keeps the legend from covering the graph.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qozjc.png):[image: XY graph with legend overlapping plot]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have moved the legend, changing it's anchor point. You can move the legend to the right side of the graph element and it should re-anchor.

Comment: I tried starting anew with a "fresh" XY graph that should still have the legend anchored, however the it too covers the trace plots when the legend auto-expands for long legend text strings.  It would seem that part of the problem is that the legend autosize option uses the upper right-hand corner of the legend as the anchor so that all expansion occurs on the left-hand side.